How MetaSpace conducts garbage collection
During the development process, I encountered an Out of Memory (OOM) issue. Upon monitoring, I found that the JVM performed a Full GC before the OOM occurred. However, the heap space usage was only 5%, while the usage of MetaSpace reached 70%. The usage ratio of MetaSpace has reached the default value of MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio, which is 70%, triggering memory recycling of MetaSpace (i.e., Full GC). In response to this phenomenon, I have a question regarding the memory recycling of the JVM's MetaSpace.
What is the process of garbage collection in MetaSpace?
I understand that the MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio parameter in the JVM can set the threshold for triggering garbage collection in MetaSpace, with a default value of 70%.
Java version: 1.8.0_411
The JVM parameters are:
-Xms6144m
-Xmx6144m 
-Xmn1600m 
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m 
-XX:MetaspaceSize=256m 
-Dfastjson.parser.autoTypeSupport=false 
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly 
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC


I have no idea what "What is the process of ..." is asking for. What exactly do you want to know?

Can you provide the complete OOM stacktrace when the JVM exits? There are different OOM types, so that will help you to identify what type of memory your run out of.

Garbage collection in MetaSpace is a bit different from the garbage collection in the Java heap. In MetaSpace, garbage collection is performed by the Concurrent Mark and Sweep (CMS) garbage collector.
Check the Oracle Doc
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/cms.html

I wouldn't expect that doc to be definitive.  Especially since CMS was removed in Java 14.
